# Tree stucture menu object to array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm stuck in tree structure menu.

Here is my table

```
+----+----------------------+----------------------+-----------+
| id | title                | slug                 | parent_id |
+----+----------------------+----------------------+-----------+
|  1 | Cameras              | cameras              |      0     |
|  2 | Lighting             | lighting             |      0     |
|  3 | Portable Lights      | portable-lights      |      2     |
|  4 | Studio Lights        | studio-lights        |      2     |
|  5 | Lighting Accessories | lighting-accessories |      3     |
|  6 | Lens                 | lens                 |      0     |
|  7 | Tripods              | tripods              |      6     |
|  8 | Accessories          | accessories          |      7     |
|  9 | Miscellaneous        | miscellaneous        |      7     |
+----+----------------------+----------------------+-----------+
```

Here is my relationship

```
public function parent(){
return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent_id');}
public function children(){
return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id');}
```

Wanted output:

```
- Cameras
- Lighting
    -- Portable Lights
        --Lighting Accessories
    -- Studio Lights
- Lens
    -- Tripods
        - Accessories
        - Miscellaneous
```

I want the above result in an array with (`id` and `title`).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so Collection pipelines are perfect for what you want to do. Here goes;

```
// Retrieve all categories and then key them by their id
$categories = Category::all()->keyBy('id');
$categories->filter(function (Category $category) {
    // We want to only grab the categories that are children
    return $category->parent_id;
})->each(function (Category $category) use($categories) {
    // We not want to get the parent of this category
    $parent = $categories->get($category->parent_id);

    if ($parent) {
        // If the parent exists, and we haven't seen it yet, set a default collection
        if (! $parent->relationLoaded('children')) {
            $parent->setRelation('children', new Collection);
        }
        // We can be confident that it's a collection and won't auto load, so we add
        $parent->children->push($category);
    }
});

// Finally we want to return only root categories
return $categories->filter(function (Category $category) {
    return ! $category->parent_id;
});
```

I've put comments through the code to hopefully explain what's happening. I've not tested this code, but it should work.

The collection should have three entries, `Cameras`, `Lighting` and `Lens`. `Lighting->children` should have 2 entries, with `Portable Lights->children` having 1. Same for `Lens->children` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Create relationship in model like

```
 public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category','parent_id','id') ;
 }
```

After that your controller action for get the categories result like

```
public function getCategoryList()
{
    $categories = Category::where('parent_id', '=', 0)->get();
    $allCategories = Category::pluck('title','id')->all();


    return view('categoryTreeMenu',compact('categories','allCategories'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoud try below solution.

**Put Your model file.**

```
public function children() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Category','parent_id','id') ;
}
```

**Your controller file.**

```
$parent = Task::where('parent_id', '=', 0)->get();
foreach($parent as $key => $value){
        if(isset($value->children)){
            $parent[$key]['children'] = $value->children;
            foreach ($parent[$key]['children'] as $key1 => $value1) {
                if(isset($value1->children)){
                }
            }
        }
}
```

You can get all children and sub children data in **$parent** array.